# UAC with UPX Shell

Tags: delphi

I have been building a UPX Shell GUI for UPX, which up until a few hours ago was working very well yesterday using two different methods to starting a console application (UPX) and redirect stdoutput.

During continued development today when I run my UPX Shell UPX compresses or decompresses the file but reports either an IOerror which I assume is caused by UAC in Windows 7 or a IORename errors when -k (backup) is an option.  When I run my UPX from the commandline ( no administrative access ) upx runs just fine.

I am testing two different ways to run a XPX commandline.  First I am testing the function "Sto_RedirectedExecute" was written by Martin Stoeckli and is part of the site: http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/delphi/.  Secoond, I am also testing PJConsoleApp.pas written by Peter Johnson of the Delphi Dabbler: http://www.delphidabbler.com/software/consoleapp?mid=3.2.  Peters classes are designed to be used to control the execution of child console application processes and to redirect input and output where required.

Using Sto_RedirectedExecute, UPX reports this:
                       Ultimate Packer for eXecutables
                          Copyright (C) 1996 - 2010
UPX 3.07w       Markus Oberhumer, Laszlo Molnar & John Reiser   Sep 08th 2010

```
    File size         Ratio      Format      Name
```

--------------------   ------   -----------   -----------
    863744 ->    351744   40.72%    win32/pe     Demo8.exe

Packed 1 file: 0 ok, 1 error.

upx: C:\Components\Dabbler\Pipes\Demos\Exe\Demo8.exe: IOException: C:\Components\Dabbler\Pipes\Demos\Exe\Demo8.exe: Permission denied

If you need more information, please ask and I will respond.

Comment: What is your *question*?

Comment: Your update still doesn't include a question. Voting to close.

Comment: My question is Why am I getting Permission denied?  UPX shows the file bing compressed and then reports Packed 1 file ok. 1 error.  When i run upx direclty from a dos box on the same file the file  is compressed and saved but i get permission denied when run from my GUI app and the output file is not saved by UPX.

Comment: I found the problem IsUPXCompressed function is causing a sharing problem with UPX itself.  See my explanation at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119948/method-to-determine-if-an-exe-file-has-been-compressed-with-upx